# Benefits of dumping from a MySQL database to JSON file?

Tags: php, mysql, json, dump

I just want to ask if there would be a difference getting a report from a MYSQL database directly or from a MYSQL database dumped JSON.

I'm new with JSON and is looking everywhere for tutorials and samples so a suggestion is highly appreciated.

My scenario would be getting data from a MYSQL database then dump this information to an external JSON file then process it with PHP.

The question is

1. Do i need to apply filters when dumping data to my JSON file depending on the users request? If so how will I do this for multiple users provided that they use different filters?
2. Is it advisable to dump the whole database to JSON from backend? If this is the case what if I have a 100MB worth of JSON file. (I already have 35MB worth of data from a 3 day database, and i need to atleast process a whole month).
3. If dumping from a JSON file results to an array how can I apply filters to it without looping through the whole array then checking values using IF STATEMENT?

I could always get the data from a MYSQL database directly using PHP. but like I said if this can be done with JSON and would result to a better performing site I would rather go for it.

Comment: Adding another step won't make your site perform better. JSON is most useful when making AJAX requests to your PHP files which return data in that format. Then your Javascript can use it easier.

Comment: it will not result in better performance.  There are mutliple more unecessary steps required in dumping all quieries to json file

Comment: databases are FAST. they're also easy to query and manage. putting all your data in a huge json file? slow and unwieldy. please don't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't do this.

There is no reason to do this for each request.  It will result in worse performance.

PHP provides all tools in standard language to [interact](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) safely with MySQL database.

> Do i need to apply filters when dumping data to my JSON file depending on the users request? If so how will I do this for multiple users provided that they use different filters?

If you needed to do this for some reason, (don't do it) then yes might as well minimize the data you get from mysql and have to write to the os

> Is it advisable to dump the whole database to JSON from backend? If
>   this is the case what if I have a 100MB worth of JSON file. (I already
>   have 35MB worth of data from a 3 day database, and i need to atleast
>   process a whole month).

No, it is not advisable to dump any data to a JSON file for a live request.  For MYSQL backups it is a good idea to back up mysql data into a file, commonly a .sql file

> If dumping from a JSON file results to an array how can I apply
>   filters to it without looping through the whole array then checking
>   values using IF STATEMENT?

This illustrates the need for a mysql tutorial.  Mysql stores data on your filesystem.  It is a highly optimized, battle tested system maed to filter results.  Do all filtering in mysql unless you have a really good reason not to

Comment: you can query mysql directly and use php to convert that data to json for the request `json_encode`

Comment: ok so correct me if im wrong. For filtering results do it directly from the database and not from the JSON file? right?

Comment: @AlexisZenigata yes it will be a new thing to learn but learning to do basic filters (selects) is pretty easy and quick to learn

Comment: Yes completely familiar with these things. It just so happens that my boss wants them to be in JSON. Now I have to tell him that this won't be possible like he wanted.

Comment: @AlexisZenigata don't get me wrong if you need your data on the front end like for a javascript graphing library ( or really for any use on the front end) you should convert your data to json but not as a flat file flow might be:
1. user requests data on front end, ajax request to php
2. php queries mysql database
3. convert to json `json_encode` and return to front end

Comment: no worries. my initial thoughts exactly going back to my first question on how will i write json with multiple users sending different request. i guess ill just go with the mysql query for now since im going to use a database that updates on a daily basis. ill just use json for static databases for the meantime